# SQL Server char(1) conversion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

in table A I have a char(1) column called **flag** that is nullable.
In table B I also have a char(1) column that is non-nullable und so I want to use ISNULL, COALESCE or CASE to set a explicit value for NULLs before I INSERT the data from table A into table B

Like so:

```
OUTER APPLY (VALUES(COALESCE(A.flag,CAST('0' AS char(1))))) AS AP(flag)
```

The **problem** is, SQL Server returns the following error message:

> Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Conversion failed when
>   converting the varchar value 'X' to data type int.

There are rows with the value 'X' in table A but why SQL Server tries to convert a char(1) column into an int? When I run the SELECT-Statement only (without the insert) I don't get the error.

What I've done so far:

- I've checked the number and right order of columns in the INSERT and the
  SELECT-Statement
- I've checked, that the selected column and the insert-column are borth 
  char(1)
- I've moved the COALESCE from the SELECT-Clause to an APPLY
- I've added OPTION (Recompile)
- There are no Triggers on Insert-Table B
- I've turned SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON 
  I cannot find any conversion Like
  Convert DataType="char" or Convert DataType="int"
- re-created the Insert-Table B
- I've replaced the source-column-name A.flag to a literal '-'
  **Here the INSERT works!**
  So there must be a problem with the flag-Column.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like it is actually another field that is throwing the error.  Are there any int fields on table b?

Comment: Hi Joe, yes there are. But when I replace the flag-Field with a literal like '-' the insert works. So, the other fields must be ok.

Comment: @CPMunich try something other than - as your literal. It can be converted to an int as 0. i.e. `select cast('-' as int)` will return 0. I hate to ask, but are you SURE the column you are inserting into is a `char(1)`?

Comment: @scsimon: Thanks. I've found the error will add an answer

Answer (score 0):

I've found out, that one of the views, referencing the table is an indexed view. The WHERE-Clause in that indexed view was wrong.
There filtering predicate was an int instead of char(1). After chaging that, the insert works fine.